# Python 3: Hashes not generating correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, got this hash generator working just the way I want it except that it does not generate the hashes correctly. I have checked some of the hashes generated from my script to those found on other websites and they keep not matching. It appears to be a problem with all hashes so I think it has to do something with the hasher function and the data.encode("utf8").

Comment: Do you have an example of some input that gives a mismatch, and what you think the output should be based on these other sites?

Comment: MD5 || My script dox=8f9b83791d441749fc80644427efd4f5 || Other Websites dox=171994ae268f7cd4f6eec68883d9c553

Comment: SHA1 || My Script auw = f5384dcd6b5d04ba7f1aab13fe1e35fa953d2950 || Other websites auw = ec2ef255c2f871a7e5cc656a2cf34be344a8c3f0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/hashlib.html):

> `hash.update(arg)`
>
> Update the hash object with the object arg, which
>   must be interpretable as a buffer of bytes. Repeated calls are
>   equivalent to a single call with the concatenation of all the
>   arguments: `m.update(a); m.update(b)` is equivalent to `m.update(a+b)`.

So you are concatenating all your combinations together.

Instead, you'll want to create a new Hash object each time `hasher` is called:

```
Hashes = {
    'MD5': hashlib.md5,
    'SHA1': hashlib.sha1,
    'SHA224': hashlib.sha224,
    'SHA256': hashlib.sha256,
    'SHA384': hashlib.sha384,
    'SHA512': hashlib.sha512
}

...

return Hash(data.encode("utf8")).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thank you! read the docs about up and down a dozen times, still new to coding so that is kinda confusing till I did a little googling and learned the definition of concatenation. :) Thx again.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Concatenation sounds confusing (and some of the definitions make it even more confusing), but it's really as simple as `"Hello " + "World!" == "Hello World!"`. In your example, you were basically calling `Hash.update("a" + "b" + "c" + "d" + ...)`.